# How to show youtube videos in web View Android

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube

I have got a web view that shows some website that has a YouTube videos embedded. It works on my THL 5000 (4.4) but when I try to start the videos on my Nexus 4 (Android 5) the videos will just start buffering but no audios neither videos is shown.

Here is what i do:

```
final WebView mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        //mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;

        mWebView.setInitialScale(100*width/768 +10);
        // disable scroll on touch
        mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
            }
        });
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);


        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
```

This is the logcat error I get when I try to run it on the nexus:

```
05-01 13:27:13.170    8662-8662/com....... E/SysUtils﹕       ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
05-01 13:27:21.057    8662-9038/com...... E/OMXMaster﹕ A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
05-01 13:27:21.178    8662-9047/com....... E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
05-01 13:27:21.196    8662-9047/com....... E/ACodec﹕ registering GraphicBuffer 0 with OMX IL component failed: -2147483648
05-01 13:27:21.196    8662-9047/com....... E/ACodec﹕ Failed to allocate buffers after transitioning to IDLE state (error 0x80000000)
05-01 13:27:21.196    8662-9047/com....... E/ACodec﹕ signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
05-01 13:27:21.196    8662-9046/com..... E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 5
05-01 13:27:21.198    8662-8662/com........ E/MediaCodecBridge﹕ Cannot start the media codec
    android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: start failed
            at android.media.MediaCodec.native_start(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaCodec.start(MediaCodec.java:612)
            at org.chromium.media.MediaCodecBridge.start(MediaCodecBridge.java:370)
            at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
            at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:53)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Thanks for any help!

Kind regards
Patric

Comment: Have you found a solution, cause i'm facing the same error atm?

Comment: Hey - unfortunately not. I had to go for another path. Wish you good luck with this issue

Comment: Damn, im really stuck at this point. But thank anyways for your reply!

Comment: You'r welcome... Sorry that I couldn't help more. It's a very annoying bug. If I find the code I can post a snippet of what I did. But I remember it was a work around...